# Drawing text in a spiral in Processing

Tags: arrays, processing, spiral

I've got an array of strings that I'd like to draw as a giant spiral.  I only have a very, very rough idea of where to begin.  First, I will probably need to break the strings into an array of individual characters?  Next, I will probably need to apply the following geometry in order to generate the spiral shape?

```
float r = 0;
float theta = 0;

void setup() {
  size(200,200);
  background(255);
}

void draw() {

  float x = r * cos(theta);
  float y = r * sin(theta);

  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x+width/2, y+height/2, 6, 6); 

  theta += 0.01;
  r += 0.05;
}
```

However, I don't know how to step through my array of characters in order to draw them in a spiral-like format. I apologize for the lack of clarity.  Any suggestions would be awesome! I'm very new to all of this (clearly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code for creating the spiral is a good idea. One way to create rotated text would be using [rotate()](http://processing.org/reference/rotate_.html), combined with [text()](http://processing.org/reference/text_.html). You would have a for loop, iterate through your character array, increment the radius, and draw your text that way. Note that `rotate()` has a cumulative effect. Something like:

```
String str = "asdflkkjsahfdlkadshflkahdslkfajsdf";
float radius = 0;
//so we are rotating around the center, rather than (0,0):
translate(width/2, height/2); 
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
  radius += 2;
  // taken out because of non-constant spacing at large radius:
  //rotate(0.5);
  // this should give constant spacing, no matter the radius
  // change 10 to some other number for a different spacing. 
  rotate(10/radius);
  // drawing at (0,radius) because we're drawing onto a rotated canvas
  text(str.charAt(i), 0, radius);
}
```

You may want to have the angle change be a function of radius, because at large radii, the letters are spaced very far apart. One way to do this would be using the equation `s = rθ`, where s is the arclength (in this case, distance between letters), r is radius, and θ is the angle change. If you want a constant distance between letters, regardless of radius, then θ would have to be proportional to 1/r. And of course, you can tweak the hard-coded values to your liking.

Also: the `rotate()` and `translate()` methods are undone at the end of `draw()`, so if you aren't doing anything after this code, then it's okay to leave it as is. If you do want to draw more stuff after, then you'll have to undo the rotation and translation manually before you draw anything else.

Edit: I just realized that I assumed you wanted the letters to be rotated as well, and not just *positioned* in a spiral but still oriented normally. In that case, you could use your existing code and replace the `ellipse(...)` with `text(str.charAt(...)...)`, with appropriate parameters of course.

Comment: Thank you -- however, I am not quite sure where/how to implement the equation s=r0 in order to prevent the extreme spacing to occur at large radii.

Comment: To make the distance between letters (which is the geometric arclength "s") a constant, then multiplying r by θ must always yield a constant. So, θ must be equal to that constant divided by r. I've added an example of this in the code in the answer so you can see what I mean.